# Trouble positioning divs inside other divs

Tags: css, html, styles, positioning

Right now I have a main div with an id of **"wrapper"**, and inside this div I am trying to make two other divs that take up about the entire width of **"wrapper"**. The first div, **"sidebar"**, is narrow and contains some information I want displayed on the far right of **"wrapper"**. The second internal div I have will be dynamically updated using php and javascript from data inserted by users, id called **"maincontent"**.

I can get them positioned inside "wrapper" fine at first. The problem comes when new content is added in the "maincontent" div. When new content is added the "sidebar" div will move down proportionally to the height of the newly added content.

So, my question is this:

How do I get the two internal divs to maintain their positions on the top of the page while still being able to extend dynamically downward without anything moving around?

Comment: Go make a fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with just the div structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to `float:left` your left-content:

see the css below:

```
  .wrapper
  {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     top:10px;
     width:100%;
     height:500px;
     background-color:yellow;
  }
  .left-content
  {
     position:relative;
     width:20%;
     background-color:red;
     height:100%;
     float:left;
  }
  .main-content
  {
     position:relative;
     width:80%;
     left:20%;
     background-color:green;
     height:100%;

  }
```

where your divs are as below:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-content">
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

what's important is, you accurately divide the width of the parent to the child containers

i.e. `total width of child containers <= parent width`

see, you need to learn about `position` attribute of css-style 
when you do `position:relative` for any container, css properties like `top, left,right,bottom` starts working for them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my fiddle, the Javascript is completely unnecessary. Let me know if it helps you, or if you have any questions left. The most important part is having `float: left` or `float: right` in both the maincontent and sidebar. 
http://jsfiddle.net/y89zp/